# php script to access multiple web pages

Tags: php, url, web

I need a function/method in php to access multiple web pages in a loop. Just as someone can manually access a web page and load any scripts on there. I'm not downloading any information I just want the script to access it so that any php code can run on that page. It's a hack for a program i'm working on that needs cron jobs running. The cron job will run one script that will load multiple pages eg. http:// localhost/program/script1, http:// localhost/program/script2. I can then dynamically add pages from a database as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

here you would just separate the code you want shared into another file and then use

```
require("/path/to/filename.php");
```

The path instead of being a url will be the filesystem path to where you saved the file.

Good starting points to reference this file is $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] so you could say something like.

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/program/script1.php");
```

Comment: I can't include or require the url's. I need to access the pages so that the scripts on them run. I don't need any data from them and they are blank cause there is no outputs. I just need to have a script automatically access them in a loop.

Comment: I got you... you need the results not the code... you should be able to use the http stream wrappers for that just do this. `echo  file_get_contents("http://localhost/program/script1");`

Comment: if you need more control over the page (like posting data to the script) then you should look into curl_* http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php or HttpRequest http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.httprequest.php

Answer (score 0):

You could scan a directory and loop through each of the files in it then read or write to it with fopen

```
$files = scandir('folder/');
  foreach($files as $file) {
   //do your work here
   $fhandle = fopen($file, 'r');
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_scandir.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php